# Re-use of xml menu template with flavors

Tags: android, xml, android-productflavors

I am currently making an app with 3 flavors. I am using a `NavigationView` inside a `DrawerLayout` for my navigation. I have specified my menu from XML in the `NavigationView` like this:

```
...
app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
...
```

and this goes for all 3 flavors. The `activity_main_drawer` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_categories"
            android:title="Categories" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_map"
            android:title="Map" />

    </group>
</menu>
```

This is used in my starting, main activity called `MainActivity`. The thing is, the applications were not supposed to differentiate anyhow, except from the API url. Now, we need to remove one of the links only for one of the apps.

The first solution I could come up with is to copy the `activity_main_drawer` to my flavor specific resource menu folder and put `android:visible="false"` which does its purpose, but then we need to maintain two menus (and it is possible to forget to update the specific flavor one). I cannot just simply remove and `<item>` from the menu in the flavor specific project, as then the ID won't be available and the application won't compile.

My other possibility is to remove the item on run-time after I have checked for the flavor the app is running.

I would like some insight on which approach is better and how to minimize the number of code/text copied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now, we need to remove one of the links only for one of the apps.

I am going to assume that by "links", you mean one of the `<item>` elements.

If so:

- Define a `boolean` resource, here called `i_can_haz_link`, to be `true` in your `main` sourceset
- Re-define the same `boolean` resource to be `false` in the flavor(s) that should not have this link
- Use `android:visible="@bool/i_can_haz_link"` in the affected `<item>`

I would go with this approach over either of the two in your question. Of the two in the question, I would probably go with the duplicate `menu` resource, just so the Java code can remain clean and unaffected.

Comment: Yes, that is actually what I was looking for!